# Migrating log4j 1.2.17 from JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final to JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jboss, log4j

I am migrating my application server from JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final to JBoss EAP 6.2. However, I am having some issues with the Apache log4j 1.2.17 and EAP 6.2.

In AS 7.1.1 I didn't have to do anything other than have the log4j.jar in the build path of the project I was working on in Eclipse. The logs I wanted were defined within the JBoss standalone.xml and were created whenever I started the server. I am using JAR files, not WAR or EAR files for the deployment of my applications.

Now when migrating to EAP 6.2 I am trying to make everything local in my Eclipse structure.
I set the per-deployment setting in the standalone.conf to false as shown below:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

I created a META-INF folder in my project src folder with the file jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="com.log4j.mylog4j" export="true" />
    </dependencies>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
</deployment>
```

I also placed the log4j.properties in the src folder with the definition of rootlogger and all of the individual loggers.

However, whenever I try to log anything within my application I get the warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want logging configured via the subsystem or via your log4j.properties file?

Comment: I would like logging to be configured via the log4j.properties file.

Comment: Is com.log4j.mylog4j a custom log4j library? If possible it would probably be easiest to put your log4j.properties in there.

Comment: That is the path in my JBoss folder where the apachi log4j.jar resides. I will give it a shot though.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Hmm.. ...maybe put it in the META-INF of your JAR file you're deploying then.

Comment: Also feel free to move this to a chat of if you're on freednode IRC join #wildfly and ping me (jamezp)

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck. I also tied using the:

Comment: I also tried the:
PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\...")
with the program I am doing the logging in with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I have multiple projects in eclipse one being a logging project with a program the controls all of my logging. So I set up my META-INF in the logging project. However, all the logging calls were made in another project with many other programs. I had to set up the META-INF in this other project NOT the logging project. Not sure why but it got rid of this error.